The meaning of “manage” in this context
What is the meaning of “manage” in this passage?

Tom and Ali, are arguing in a very angry way all the time. It started when Tom used Ali’s computer and managed to destroy some files. Now Ali won't let him use the computer without breathing down his neck all the time and he's always going on about how stupid Tom was.

I looked up in some dictionaries, but I could not find a meaning that is related to this context.
The meaning of "manage" in the Cambridge Dictionary: to succeed in doing or dealing with something, especially something difficult

The meaning of "manage" here is sarcastic. It suggests that Tom is incompetent and "succeeded" in doing something that he should not have done.

The use of managed is not in the sense of to succeed in doing or dealing with something, especially something difficult. That would suggest a malicious act from Tom, but the context says otherwise: this is likely a case of Tom's carelessness or lack of intelligence.    The word is used ironically, and Collins Dictionary in its third sense 6 illustrates a similar use:

... often used ironically [he managed to make a mess of it]


I take issue with the Cambridge definition.
"To manage" is to deal with the (possibly changing or otherwise difficult) circumstances before you as you attempt to accomplish something.
The verb doesn't entail the meaning "to accomplish a goal". You might not deal very well with the circumstances before you.
And so this is not an apt definition of "to manage": "To accomplish a goal by dealing with the (possibly changing or otherwise difficult) circumstances before you.
The lexicographers are confusing ellipsis in context with entailed meaning.

Did you manage to get your car started?
-- Yes, I managed [to get my car started].

The outcome of your management is the actual outcome, for good or ill. And so we can say

I tried to fix it but I managed to make it worse.

The infinitival clause complement expresses the outcome.

I. Meaning of "managed to" in the passage..
OP's query:

It started when Tom used Ali’s computer and managed to destroy some files. What is the meaning of “manage” in this passage?

In the case of "Tom managed to destroy some files", the meaning of "manage to" is being used in a sense that's a bit different from the Cambridge Dictionary definition.
Though it doesn't  mean that Tom accomplished something difficult, the phrase "managed to" in this instance suggests that his activities had the unintended result of destroying files.
Rather than actively succeeding in achieving something, this word is more equivalent to "managed to," meaning "happened to" or "ended up" doing something. It's a more casual, conversational way of saying that Tom did something unintentionally.
II. Is the use of "manage to" ambiguous".
"Managed to" is frequently used to imply unexpectedness or surprise in informal conversation or storytelling, even when the result is unfavourable. Although it's a widespread idiom, in formal or technical contexts it might not be the most accurate choice.
In formal writing or more precise language, you might rephrase it to:

"Tom inadvertently destroyed some files..."
"Tom accidentally deleted some files..."
"Tom's actions resulted in the loss of some files..."

These alternatives make it clear that the destruction of files was unintentional.

I'm not sure that irony must be "informal"; it's just that there are many formal contexts where opinion and rhetoric are supposed to be limited (research, etc.). An opinion essay, even in a formal journal, could certainly employ sarcasm.
